# How to trim data with last alphanumeric key as reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need your help on below Data trimming or what so ever to get the result that shows also on below. I want to get the data where my reference is the last **`-`** symbol.

See example below.

```
   FROM                  TO
  +-------------------------------+
  |ABC-1234-AR-R  | ABC-1234-AR   |
  |ABC-1254-AR-IT | ABC-1254-AR   |
  |ABC-1223-AR-LTL| ABC-1223-AR   |
  |ABC-1234-R     | ABC-1234      |
  +-------------------------------+
```

Comment: The fourth record isn't being trimmed, it has stuff being added to it.  Maybe update your question and give us the logic behind your intended update.

Comment: The logic behind this is to trim data based on the last "-" symbol any string or char that is after the "-" symbol will be trimmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you index of last occurence of a hyphen:

```
LEN(data) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(data)) + 1
```

So it's enough to take substring of this length:

```
SELECT
    data,
    SUBSTRING(data, 1, LEN(data) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(data))) AS data_trimmed
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen You're right, I mistakenly considered comma instead of a hyphen. corrected answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Cheers! got it! now i know the logic behind this, i need to reverse the starting position of the string! Answer accepted!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you very much. Very often I mess parameters in `CHARINDEX` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a combination of **`LEFT`** and **`CHARINDEX`** functions.

**Query**

```
select [from], 
left([from], len([from]) - charindex('-', reverse([from]), 1)) as [to]
from [your_table_name];
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/889663/how-to-trim-data-with-last-alphanumeric-key-as-reference)**